# Get consistent md5 checksum of gzipped file using data.table and R.utils

Tags: r, data.table, gzip

I'm trying to replicate the checksum of a compressed file with `R.utils::gzip` and the `compress = "gzip"` argument of `data.table::fwrite` but I keep getting different results. Here is an example

```r
library(data.table); library(R.utils); library(digest)

dt <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3))

fwrite(dt, "r-utils.csv")
gzip("r-utils.csv")
fwrite(dt, "datatable-v1.csv.gz", compress = "gzip")

digest(file = "r-utils.csv.gz")
#> [1] "8d4073f4966f94ac5689c6e85de2d92d"
digest(file = "datatable-v1.csv.gz")
#> [1] "5d58f9eeefb166c6d50ac00f3215e689"
```

Initially I though that `fwrite` was storing the filename and timestamp in the output file (per the usual `gzip` behaviour without the `--no-name` option), but that don't appear to be the case since I get the same checksum in different calls to `fwrite`

```r
fwrite(dt, "datatable-v2.csv.gz", compress = "gzip")
digest(file = "datatable-v2.csv.gz")
#> [1] "5d58f9eeefb166c6d50ac00f3215e689"
```

Any ideas on what might be causing the difference?

PS. Incidentally, the checksum of the uncompressed files are the same

```sh
$ md5sum datatable-v1.csv 
7e034138dc91aa575d929c1ed65aa67c  datatable-v1.csv
$ md5sum r-utils.csv 
7e034138dc91aa575d929c1ed65aa67c  r-utils.csv
```

Comment: *"`fwrite` was storing the filename and timestamp in the output file (per the usual `gzip` behavior...)"* seems quite off: `fwrite` writes the CSV-formatted data into a file, and names it the filename that you provide. The timestamp of the save is done by the operating system, nothing to do with `fwrite` or even R. `gzip` doesn't even store the original timestamp, and it "knows" the original name based on the premise that the original name is the current gzipped name with the trailing `.gz` removed. These utilities are relatively na&iuml;ve for good reason: simplicity is a good thing.

Comment: The problem is you, in that you think you need to be able to get the exact same file from two different compressors with the same input. There is never any guarantee for that. Different compression code, the same compression code with different settings, or a new version of the same compression code with the same settings, all can legitimately produce different output for the same input. If you think you need the same output, you will only experience frustration and disappointment for no reason. If you need to assure integrity, then check the **decompressed** data, not the compressed data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the bytes, you can see they are different

```
r-utils.csv.gz
  Offset: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F   
00000000: 1F 8B 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 4B E4 E5 32 E4 E5    ..........Kde2de
00000010: 32 E2 E5 32 E6 E5 02 00 21 EB 62 BF 0C 00 00 00    2be2fe..!kb?....
```

and

```
datatable-v2.csv.gz
  Offset: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F   
00000000: 1F 8B 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A 4B E4 E5 02 00 56    ..........Kde..V
00000010: EF 2F E3 03 00 00 00 1F 8B 08 00 00 00 00 00 00    o/c.............
00000020: 0A 33 E4 E5 32 E2 E5 32 E6 E5 02 00 49 C4 FF 4D    .3de2be2fe..ID.M
00000030: 09 00 00 00                                        ....
```

So the data.table one is longer. This appears to be because the default compression settings are different. Specifically it looks like the two method use a different "window size" parameter. The [data.table code uses a windowBits value of 31 (15+16)](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/c3d1100cf814ee16d003f8ab294dcf8e93d75d16/src/fwrite.c#L567) which will include "trailing checksum in the output" but the `R.utils::gzip` function uses the base R `gzfile()` function [which uses a windowBits value of -15 (MAX_WBITS)](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/79298c499218846d14500255efd622b5021c10ec/src/main/gzio.h#L225) and that negative value means a trailing checksum should not be used. So I think that accounts for the extra bytes in the in the data.table output.

Because you can use different compression level settings and checksums and gzip headers, it's not necessarily the case the you will get the same checksum for compressed versions of data files if two different compression pipelines are used. So it's possible for the data inside to be identical but the actual compressed files to be different.

Since these settings are part of the C code for the package and for base R this is not something you will be able to change in R code. It's not possible for these two different methods to return identical output.